# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/set/MapBackedSet

Tags: spring, classnotfound

**I am using SpringFrameWorkVersion 5.2.0.M3 and common-collections version 4.2.
While building my project getting below error** :

*java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/set/MapBackedSet
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1791)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)*

Comment: Could you please share the pom.xml file. We can't find the issues just with this trace

Comment: welcome to stack overflow :-) please show us an [mcve] or an excerpt of your code that causes the stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a conflict between two versions of **Commons Collections**, I way to resolve the problem is to add in the pom file the tag  with the version of the library which in this case is 4.4.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your dependencies?
It seems to some conflicts in dependency.